# Google Maps V3 save map position after user used drag&drop

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So I display a map on my website and I want after the user has used his mouse to drag around the map and hits a submit button on the site to save the current map status, in order to display it later on, so what I need is to get the current `lat and long` of the map after the user has used the map.

So afterwards if the user comes back I can display the same map by setiing `LatLng`

```
<script 
type="text/javascript" 
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&callback=initialize"></script>
function initialize() {
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
}
```

//LE

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&callback=initialize"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;

    function initialize() {
        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
    }


    $(window).load(function(){
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    });
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var currentLL = map.getCenter(); // you can even store it in localStorage
        var currentZoom = map.getZoom();

        console.log(currentLL);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Once the user hits the submit button, get the center position(lat/lng) of the Google Maps.  This is the wise option to retain the map.

```
var currentLL = map.getCenter(); // you can even store it in localStorage
var currentZoom = map.getZoom(); // better to save zoom level too
```

once you return back to maps, set it has center

```
map.setCenter(currentLL);
map.setZoom(currentZoom);
```

Comment: I have tried that already and it doesn't work: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCenter' of undefined`

Comment: @Uffo that because you have the `map` variable within a function scope..  declare it as a global variable and try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Praveen's solution, but don't place that code in document ready function. Place it in a separate function and call that function when the user hits the save button.

Or you can use the Maps API event listeners for that.

You mentioned that you want to save the location when hitting a button **and** *after the user has used his mouse to drag around the map*. I suggest that you get the center and zoom when the map becomes `idle`. That is, *when the map becomes idle after panning or zooming*. See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map).

You could use the `dragend` event but that would not work if the user only changed the zoom level.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {

    currentLL = map.getCenter();
    currentZoom = map.getZoom();

    console.log(currentLL, currentZoom);
});
```

This way, you always have the latest center and zoom level available.

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/vLpaxke6/)</kbd>